# React render: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me. I don't know why this piece of code doesn't work.

It gives me an error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {itemss}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
  Why {i.title} is an object. It's just a string. How can i fix this? and How actually I can iterate nested objects?

```
class ShopItem extends React.Component {

render() {
    var items = [
        {
            link: 'first link',
            title: 'Emery NEM XF',
            price: '$950'
        },
        {
            link: 'second link',
            title: 'Emery NEM XF',
            price: '$950'
        },
        {
            link: 'third link',
            title: 'Emery NEM XF',
            price: '$950'
        }
    ];


     const item = items.map((i) =>{

          return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> )
    });

        return (
            {items} 
        )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShopItem /> , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: The return inside your `map` is missing a `)`. Instead use `return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> );` — or drop the parentheses all together and use `return <h1>{i.title}</h1>;

Comment: I added  ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> ) but it's still not working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is because you return

```
return (
        {items} 
    )
```

which is an equivalent of `return ({items: items})` ie. you are returning an object with key `items` and `React doesn't expect objects for rendering`. You could either write

```
   const items = items.map((i) =>{
      return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> )
   });

   return items;
```

or

```
     return items.map((i) =>{
        return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> )
     });
```

or

```
  const items = items.map((i) =>{
      return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> )
   });

  return <React.Fragment>
        {items} 
    </React.Fragment>
```

> P.S. Note that the first two approaches will work from `react v16.0.0
>   onwards` while the last will work from `v16.2` onwards.

However if you are using a lower version, you would need to wrap the return element within a container like

```
    return (
        <div>{items}</div> 
    )
```

Comment: Is it `item` or `items` inside the `React.Fragment`?

Comment: @Raviteja, updated my answer, I hope its clear now, I should be the mapped result

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
        {items} 
    )
```

1. In the above line, you render the "items" list. You should render the "item" list which you have create from the map function of the "items" list.
2. And you should be render it into an element.

   class ShopItem extends React.Component {

   render() {
       var items = [
           {
               link: 'first link',
               title: 'Emery NEM XF',
               price: '$950'
           },
           {
               link: 'second link',
               title: 'Emery NEM XF',
               price: '$950'
           },
           {
               link: 'third link',
               title: 'Emery NEM XF',
               price: '$950'
           }
       ];

   ```
    const item = items.map((i) =>{

         return ( <h1>{i.title}</h1> )
   });

   return (
       <div>
       {item} 
       </div>
   )
   ```

   }
   }

ReactDOM.render( , document.querySelector('#root'));

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `items` in JSX in your return statement:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {items}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Your final return statement currently is not inside JSX. It's plain old JavaScript that is constructing an object like `{items: items}` thanks to [enhanced object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Enhanced_Object_literals), which is why React is saying you are giving it an item with key `items`.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
return (
    <div>
        {items.map(i) => (
            <h1>{i.title}</h1>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

edit: in react, return/render can not have a structure like

```
<h1>{i.title}</h1>
<h1>{i.title}</h1>
<h1>{i.title}</h1>
```

you should wrap them in a `<div>` or another element. also you JS was wrong which I corrected

Comment: The function you pass to `map` should either use curly brackets or remove the `return` keyword. Right now it's invalid syntax.

Comment: @RossAllen correct, it was a quick write. didn't pay attention. will edit